# Terminal shows non-ascii? characters in UTF-16 hex codes

Tags: terminal, locale, unicode, fish

```
todoroki@todoroki-VJZ13B ~>printf "ä\n"
                           echo "ä"
                           ä
ä
ä
\udcc3\udca4: \u30b3\u30de\u30f3\u30c9\u304c\u898b\u3064\u304b\u308a\u307e\u305b\u3093
```

according to a [UTF-16 decode tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf16-decode), `\u30b3\u30de\u30f3\u30c9\u304c\u898b\u3064\u304b\u308a\u307e\u305b\u3093` is `コマンドが見つかりません` (= "command not found"), which is the correct Japanese output I expect.

From the printf and echo result, UTF-8 seems working correctly.

<strike>This happens in all shell outputs, such as `ls` (Japanese characters in filenames shows up in UTF-16 hex format)</strike>
**EDIT:** `ls` output was not utf-16, but something called "Octal Escape Sequence" (where `月` becomes `\346\234\210`)

`ls` in a directory which contains 3 folders named `C`, `あいう`, and `月` outputs:

```
todoroki@todoroki-VJZ13B ~/test> ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 todoroki todoroki 4096 10月  4 15:02  C/
drwxr-xr-x 2 todoroki todoroki 4096 10月 11 09:04 ''$'\343\201\202\343\201\204\343\201\206'/
drwxr-xr-x 2 todoroki todoroki 4096 10月 11 09:05 ''$'\346\234\210'/
```

(and this is weird because `月` of the file creation dates are shown correctly, while the directory name one isn't)

`less` `vi` `nano` behaves more strange; a file (a.txt, created with gedit) like below

```
あ
い
う
ä
```

will show as

in `less` (it complains `"a.txt" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?`):

```
<E3><81><82>
<E3><81><84>
<E3><81><86>
<C3><A4>
```

in `vi`:

```
�~A~B
�~A~D
�~A~F
ä
```

and in `nano`:

```
 ^a^b
 ^a^d
 ^a^f
```

I don't remember what I had done, but it was correctly showing Japanese letters at least two days ago (and for more than 6 months).

What could be the problem and the way to recover from this?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - did you change any `locale` settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had accidentally updated my `fish` config file to read `~/.profile`,
which included a line saying `locale=C`.

I changed this to `locale=C_UTF8` and everything recovered.